# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

hi i have just created an app that saves data from in the tables with one to one mappings

[image: onetoone database contains table instructor and instructor_detail]
whenever i am trying to save data in the table so i am getting following error.

```
`Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.mapping.onetoone.Instructor.theInstructorDetail references an unknown entity: com.mapping.onetoone.InstructorDetail`
```

here is my code with @Entity and OneToOne annotations 
**Instructor.java**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name="first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name="last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name="email")
private String email;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL   )
@JoinColumn(name="instructor_detail_id")
private InstructorDetail theInstructorDetail;

public Instructor(){}

public Instructor(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
    super();
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public InstructorDetail getTheInstructorDetail() {
    return theInstructorDetail;
}

public void setTheInstructorDetail(InstructorDetail theInstructorDetail) {
    this.theInstructorDetail = theInstructorDetail;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Instructor [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email
            + ", theInstructorDetail=" + theInstructorDetail + "]";
}
```

here is my **InstructorDetail.java**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name="youtube_channel")
private String youTubeChannel;

@Column(name="hobby")
private String hobby;

public InstructorDetail(){}

public InstructorDetail(String youTubeChannel, String hobby) {
    super();
    this.youTubeChannel = youTubeChannel;
    this.hobby = hobby;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getYouTubeChannel() {
    return youTubeChannel;
}

public void setYouTubeChannel(String youTubeChannel) {
    this.youTubeChannel = youTubeChannel;
}

public String getHobby() {
    return hobby;
}

public void setHobby(String hobby) {
    this.hobby = hobby;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "InstructorDetail [id=" + id + ", youTubeChannel=" + youTubeChannel + ", hobby=" + hobby + "]";
}
```

**CreateInstructor.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SessionFactory factory=new Configuration().configure("hibernate1.cfg.xml")
            .addAnnotatedClass(Instructor.class).buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Object created. Now creating Instructor object...");
        Instructor ins=new Instructor("elon", "musk", "elonmusk@hotmail.com");

        System.out.println("Creating InstructorDetail object...");
        InstructorDetail theInstructorDetail=new InstructorDetail("vella Panti Adda", "Acting");

        ins.setTheInstructorDetail(theInstructorDetail);

        session.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println("Saving data....");

        session.save(ins);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        System.out.println("Data saved!");

    }
    finally
    {
        factory.close();
    }
}
```

can anyone help me.

Comment: is `InstructorDetail` annotated with `@Entity`?

Comment: Not sure, but probably you would also need to `.addAnnotatedClass(InstructorDetail.class)` so that hibernate knows that it should persist `InstructorDetail` objects too.

Comment: Can you paste the whole files? with annotations and packages

Comment: hey @ThomasKläger you're right now i have just replaced `SessionFactory factory=new Configuration().configure("hibernate1.cfg.xml")
            .addAnnotatedClass(Instructor.class).buildSessionFactory();` with `SessionFactory factory=new Configuration().configure("hibernate1.cfg.xml")
            .addAnnotatedClass(Instructor.class).addAnnotatedClass(InstructorDetail.class).buildSessionFactory();` now it is working. Thank you @ThomasKläger

Answer (score 0):

you have tried this.

```
public Instructor(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
    super();
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
    this.theInstructorDetail= new InstructorDetail();
}
```

I think you should start all the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

## OneToOne Uni-directional Association

Your code setup points to `OneToOne Unidirectional Association` with InstructorDetail being parent and Instructor is child association. For this to work, you should persist/save InstructorDetail before you persist/save Instructor entity.

> ```
> session.beginTransaction();
> session.save(theInstructorDetail);
> session.save(ins);
> session.getTransaction().commit();
> ```

## OneToOne Bi-directional Association

If you don't want to associate FK in DB then create bi-directional association in java hibernate:

**Instructor.java**

```
@OneToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "instructor_detail_id")
 private InstructorDetail theInstructorDetail;
```

**InstructorDetail.java**

```
 @OneToOne(mappedBy="instructor_detail")
 private Instructor theInstructor;
```

**Persist Logic**

```
Instructor ins=new Instructor("elon", "musk", "elonmusk@hotmail.com");
InstructorDetail theInstructorDetail=new InstructorDetail("vella Panti Adda", "Acting");
ins.setTheInstructorDetail(theInstructorDetail);
theInstructorDetail.setTheInstructor(ins);
session.beginTransaction();
session.save(theInstructorDetail);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

## Recommended Structure

If you can make changes to your DB, I would suggest one of the following:

### Option A): Better

Make `Instructor` as primary table & `InstructorDetail` as secondary, logically makes more sense. That is, delete `instructor_detail_id` column from `Instructor` table & add `instructor_id` column in InstructorDetail table. Then, just flip the hibernate annotation config in the java class (opposite of what described above).

### Option B): Best

Since its a OnetoOne relationship, to reduce indexing footprint on memory, use same PK `Instructor_Id` for both the tables. And then you can use `@MapsId` annotation and not having to use `Bi-directional association`.

**InstructorDetail.java**

```
 @OneToOne
 @MapsId
 private Instructor theInstructor;
```

Comment: but i don't want to make it bi-directional it should save the information from `Instructor` and the object of `InstructorDetail` is depend on Instructor